# Python: Data analysis using FFT

Tags: python, fft

I have a [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7um2WC4G6FFazF1eXJHRVNqVFU) which looks like this:

```
YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS,  ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean,   ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) std
2016-04-20 00:00:00,1006.0515000000001,0.029159119281803602
2016-04-20 00:01:00,1006.039666666667,0.03565211699642609
2016-04-20 00:02:00,1006.0148333333334,0.036891580347842706
2016-04-20 00:03:00,1006.0058333333335,0.03351152934243721
2016-04-20 00:04:00,1005.9714999999999,0.03155973620213212
2016-04-20 00:05:00,1005.955666666667,0.027207094455343653
.............
```

I'm interested in the Pressure mean which is sampled every minute.
My goal is to look for periodic frequencies inside the data.

I've tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from scipy.fftpack import fft
    df3 = pd.read_csv('Pressure - Dates by Minute.csv', sep=",", skiprows=0)
    Pressure = df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean']
    frate = 1/60
    Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure[0])
    freqs = fft.fftfreq(len(Pfft), 1/frate)
```

But i'm getting "tuple index out of range" errors

Any ideas on how to analyze the fft and plot the matching frequencies against the raw data?

The raw data looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that there is data in `Pressure`? Try printing out the `len(Pressure)`

Comment: Yes I did, it's 28171

Comment: I am assuming, but is the last line you give the one that is giving you the errors?

Comment: No, it's the "Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure[0])" line

Comment: Your `Pressure` is  a Pandas _Series_, roughly speaking a numpy _ndarray_ and you compute its DFT by `Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure)` (no indexing!). — I don't know if this problem is or isn't related to the issue that you showed us.

Comment: When you look at `Pressure[0]` what is in that index?

Comment: The value is 1006.0515

Comment: You can just count out the maxima per day, I see two :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retrieving only the first element of `Pressure` but you should do the fourier analysis on all samples. If you replace

```
Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure[0])
```

with

```
Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure)
```

it works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df3 = pd.read_csv('Pressure - Dates by Minute.csv', sep=",", skiprows=0)
Pressure = df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean']
frate = 1. / 60
Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure)
Pfft[0] = 0  # Set huge DC component to zero, equates to Pressure = Pressure - numpy.mean(Pressure)

freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(Pfft), 1. / frate)
plt.plot(freqs, Pfft)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a stab at this, I think that the issue is that `Pressure[0]` is a value and you need to pass an array to `np.fft.fft()` so try `Pfft = np.fft.fft(Pressure)`